# Conditionally merging two collections with LINQ-to-Objects

Tags: .net, linq, collections, linq-to-objects

I need help finding the most efficient way to merge two in-memory collections with LINQ-to-Objects.  In my case, it's not a simple join or concat because certain items need to be excluded based on a property value.

Let's use the following example (not very realistic, but it illustrates what I need):

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    ...
}
```

Note, an Employee may also be a Customer.

I have a list of Employees and a list of Customers and want to generate a list of all Persons following these rules:

1. All Customers that are not also Employees
2. All Employees that are not also Customer AND are not terminated (TerminationDate == null)
3. All Persons that are both Customers and Employees AND are not terminated (TerminationDate == null)

What's the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: A customer can't be an employee anyway, because they're different classes. Do you mean "Exclude any customer which **has the same name** as an employee"?

Comment: Since persons obviously can be both Employee and Customer at the same time inheritance might not be the most appropriate way to model your objects. I would favor composition over inheritance in this case.

Comment: Yes, when I said an Employee may also be a Customer, I meant in the real world and not the objects.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Because both subclass Person, the result of the query will be a list of Person objects, so this model is appropriate to the problem at-hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not necessarily incorrect, James' example is a bit more complicated that I was hoping for and is incomplete as I need a single list as the end result.

Not sure this is the best solution, either, but here's what I came up with so far:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public override Boolean Equals(Object other)
    {
        var otherPerson = other as Person;

        if (otherPerson == null)
            return false;

        return Name.Equals(otherPerson.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public DateTime? TerminationDate { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    ...
}


public class People
{
    private IEnumerable<Customer> Customers;
    private IEnumerable<Employee> Employees;

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetCurrentPeople()
    {
        // Find all customers that are not employees
        var onlyCustomers = Customers.Except(Employees);

        // We only want employees that have not been terminated
        var currentEmployees = Employees.Where(e => e.TerminationDate == null);

        // Find all customers that are also employees
        var customerAndEmployees = currentEmployees.Intersect(Customers);

        // Now deal with employees that are not customers
        var onlyEmployees = currentEmployees.Except(Customers);

        // Join the lists together
        var mergedRules = onlyCustomers.Concat(onlyEmployees).Concat(customerAndEmployees);

        return mergedRules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell for sure, but assuming Jon's guess of name-matching is right, then does this make conceptual sense?

Note that it currently does multiple iteration, so I'd normally add ToArray or the like in some places, but I didn't want to add that into this code while trying to validate the conceptual bit.

```
var allPeople = ...;

var customers = allPeople.OfType<Customer>();
var employees = allPeople.OfType<Employee>();

var employeeNames = new HashSet(employees.Select(p => p.Name));
var customerNames = new HashSet(employees.Select(p => p.Name));

// list item #1
var customersNotEmployees = customers
    .Where(c => employeeNames.Contains(c.Name) == false);

// will be used by #2 and #3
var employeesNotTerminated = employees
    .Where(e => e.TerminationDate == null);

// list item #2
var employeesNotCustomersAndNotTerminated = employeesNotTerminated
    .Where(e => customerNames.Contains(e.Name) == false);

// list item #3
var employeesAndCustomersAndNotTerminated = employeesNotTerminated
    .Where(e => customerNames.Contains(e.Name) == true);
```